# How can i calculate body mass index (BMI)?

Tags: calculation

Is it standard measure to say if someone is fit or not.
Iam 20 years old male weight 75kg,
Height 5.5ft.

Comment: See: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10001/how-can-you-do-a-bmi-test and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/15861/does-bmi-really-matter

Comment: In my opinion no, this is the dumbest way to tell if someone fit. But insurance companies use it. Examples are weightlifters (elite) are they obese at category 81 kg, no but according to their BMI yes.